# How to make a picture cropper (only client-side concerned)?

Tags: javascript

How to make a picture cropper? Only plain-vanilla JS!

Answer (score 2):

You want plain vanilla JS only, but still: There is a Prototype/Scriptaculous based cropper available:

http://www.defusion.org.uk/code/javascript-image-cropper-ui-using-prototype-scriptaculous/

Obviously however, the actual cropping of the image file is done using PHP. I don't think there is any way to do that in Javascript. No sane way, anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [this](http://dev.vizuina.com/cropper/)!

#### Pure JavaScript Image Crop Component

- Easy to use, no special markup needed (jump to instructions).
- ZERO dependencies. Doesn't need jQuery or any other framework, but plays well with them.
- Compatible with every major browser, including Internet Explorer 7!
- Configurable aspect ratio, minimum and maximum dimensions, etc.
- Small footprint (just ~8.1 KB when minified).

#### Instructions

1. Include the JS and CSS files:
2. Add your image to your HTML document. Absolutely no other HTML markup is required:
3. Initialize the Cropper, and you're good to go!

   document.getElementById('image').onload = function () {
       new Cropper(this, {
           // options
       });
   }

Answer (score 0):

This tool can make cropped images : http://www.pixastic.com/. It is Open source and downloadable, so you might get inspiration from it.

Comment: Huh? What's the problem? It does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I have scripts of such croppers, but it is hard to study somebody else's code. I would like to make it from scratch. I learn JS so it is important for me to code it by myself.

Comment: irrelevant answer